# Dynamically insert into layout xml of Magento

Tags: magento

Im a newbie at Magento. Im trying to build a module which dynamically inserts code xml into layout xml before its rendered -
something similar to how CMS>pages have been build.

Just like how we can specify layout xml in the design section of a page (admin > cms > page), I would like to insert into layout.xml through my module.

Basically, I would like to

- have an admin section from where I can enter layout code through a
  form and store in database - I have figured out this part
- have Magento pull these pieces of code stored in the database and create an xml file before the layout files are aggregated and interpreted. - Im unable to build this portion.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a little enlightment
You can add those layout xml by using observer,
Let's say you want those layout xml added before the xml is generated

We can use event `controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before`

Here's the sample code (in `config.xml`)

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
            <observers>
                <add_new_layout>
                    <class>test/observer</class>
                    <method>addNewLayout</method>
                </add_new_layout>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Here's the `Observer.php`

```
public function addNewLayout($observer){
    $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
    $update = $layout->getUpdate();

    //$action = $observer->getEvent()->getAction();
    //$fullActionName = $action->getFullActionName();
    //in case you're going to add some conditional (apply these new layout xml on these action or other things, you can modify it by yourself)

    //here is the pieces of layout xml you're going to load (you get it from database)
    $xml = "<reference name='root'><remove name='footer'></remove></reference>";
    $update->addUpdate($xml);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another posibility is to use the `core_layout_update_updates_get_after`-event and a placeholder (non-existing) layout xml:

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <foobar>
                <file>foo/bar.xml</file>
            </foobar>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <core_layout_update_updates_get_after>
            <observers>
                <foobar>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>foobar/observer</class>
                    <method>coreLayoutUpdateUpdatesGetAfter</method>
                </foobar>
            </observers>
        </core_layout_update_updates_get_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Example PHP in your observer:

```
/**
 * Event dispatched when loading the layout
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function coreLayoutUpdateUpdatesGetAfter($observer)
{
    /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element $updates */
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('foobar/general/enabled')) {
        $file = Mage::getStoreConfig('foobar/general/layout_xml');
        if (!empty($file)) {
            $updates = $observer->getUpdates();
            if ($updates->foobar) {
                $updates->foobar->file = $file;
            }
        }
    }
}
```